# shadow dom <slot> tag in firefox

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, slot

Is there a way to make the shadow dom's `<slot>` element work in firefox?

As a work around i'm currently adding all my content from an object with a `for loop` and `.innerHTML` (see below) but this is a rather ugly method.

webcomponents.js is added as first script tag in the `head`

html

```
<portfolio-container></portfolio-container>
```

js

```
const allContent = [{
        title: "hello",
    }, {
        title: "hello",
    }];

for (var i = 0; i < allContent.length; i++) {
    shadowRoot.innerHTML += "<portfolio-item data-title='"+ allContent[i].title +"'></port-item>";
  }
```

Comment: documentFragments would be better than re-parsing the whole container HTML each array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the a library to polyfill the Shadow DOM "v1" specification that is called [shadydom](https://github.com/webcomponents/shadydom).

Before using the Sadow DOM API, load the **shadydom.min.js** file from a `<script>` element.

```
<script src="shadydom.min.js"></script>

<div id="RootDiv">
  <span>Content</span>
</div>

<script>
   var div = document.querySelector( '#RootDiv' )
   div.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
      .innerHTML = 'Content:<slot></slot>'
</script>
```

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#RootDiv')
div.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
   .innerHTML = 'This is the content:<slot></slot>'
```

```html
<head>
    <base href="https://rawgit.com/">
    
    <!--Array.from() polyfill for IE
    <script src="joshuacerbito/d6599f1c4a218e722a03514c3dbff1c2/raw/4c43e6346ca48d66344c9b35fe7381b883ec2b32/array_from_polyfill.js"></script>-->
  
    <!--Shadow DOM polyfill for Firefox and IE-->
    <script src="webcomponents/shadydom/master/shadydom.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <h4>Simple Shady</h4>
    <div id="RootDiv">
      <span>Content</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I previously added the shadow dom with `this.createShadowRoot()` (this way i got the shadow dom working in firefox) but it doesn't seem to work with `attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )`. `TypeError: this.attachShadow is not a function`

Comment: @servinlp you should not use webcomponents.js if you load shadydom.min.js